# Migrating Windows files with bad practices to case-sensitive Linux sever

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, .htaccess

I am migrating all the data from an old Windows FTP server to a Linux environment, and have run into some issues.

The people who were previously uploading files (usually simple html files and images) were following the very poor practice of capitalizing some characters in the folder and file names, then entering the filenames with incorrect case in their html code. They have also been sending out hyperlinks to those files in all lowercase. Since the server was windows, and case-insensitive, it was simply forgiving this and everything would function fine regardless.

Now that the files have migrated to a case-sensitive file system. These hyperlinks are broken, and the improperly coded HTML files will not work.

I have been toying with several solutions. Right now my plan is to use an .htaccess to make all requests case insensitive, but I wanted to make sure I am thinking of any adverse effects this might have. I know it could have a serious effect on dynamically generated pages or links, but since this is just a simple staging server, and we only use it to show sample files, we aren't going to be doing any of that anyway.

Would this also effect href tags in html code? 
Are there some other serious consequences of this that I may not be thinking of?

I just wanted to get a few other opinions and options together.
Is there a better way to tackle this issue?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had pretty good luck with the spelling correction provided by Apache's [mod_speling](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html) which has the advantage that you don't have to modify the existing file/directory names, nor the existing HTML code,  but your mileage may vary:

> It does its work by comparing each document name in the requested directory against the requested document name without regard to case, and (optionally) allowing up to one misspelling (character insertion / omission / transposition or wrong character). A list is built with all document names which were matched using this strategy.
>
> If, after scanning the directory,
>
> - no matching document was found, Apache will proceed as usual and return a "document not found" error.
> - only one document is found that "almost" matches the request, then it is returned in the form of a redirection response.
> - more than one document with a close match was found, then the list of the matches is returned to the client, and the client can select the correct candidate.

Enable by setting:

```
CheckSpelling On
```

in your httpd.conf in a VirtualHost and/or Directory block (or even a .htaccess file).

You can limit the spelling correction to lower/upper case changes only with:

```
CheckCaseOnly On
```

Comment: I didn't even know about this mod! I'll give this a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Worked Perfectly to solve this issue!

I enabled mod_speling and added the following to my httpd.conf:
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
RewriteEngine On

Apache now checks, and corrects to the proper case. I used CheckCaseOnly so it doesn't try to find other filenames. 

Thanks again HBruijn!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go with .htaccess rules. It might get complicated in the end if there are a lot of files/folder and so on.

**What I would do:** write a bash script that will convert all files and folders to lower case. Just to be sure that everything is lower case, no caps at all.

*Not sure if I got it right but you're saying that the hyperlinks are all lower case. If that's the case, having all the file names converted to lower case should solve your problem.*

You can use a simple bash script like this (let's call it rename:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter full path: "
read FULLPATH

for item in `find $FULLPATH -depth`
do
    DST=`dirname "${item}"`/`basename "${item}" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
    if [ "${item}" != "${DST}" ]
    then
        [ ! -e "${DST}" ] && mv -T "${item}" "${DST}" || echo "${item} was not renamed"
    fi
done
```

I would create a **backup copy first** (of all the files and folders, just in case).

Simply save the script, make it executable (**chmod +x rename.sh**) and then RUN it. It will ask for a full path (where the files/folders are located). Then it will search recursively for all the files and folders and convert the ones containing CAPS to lower caps.

**UPDATE:**

If you do not want to modify the links and the referrences in the html files (the ones with CAPS) you could take this approach:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Please keep in mind that the rewrite rules above are meant to be used inside the apache config file (vhost configuration) and not in an .htaccess file

For other options you could check this link as well:
https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/

Comment: I wish it were all that simple, unfortunately, the HTML docs, have not been written just in all lowercase, in some instances they are just in the wrong case. I am seeing some instances where they wrote the directory with an uppercase first letter, when the actual directory is in all lowercase.

Comment: Though, I could do both I suppose. Rename all the file/folder names to all lowercase, then use an .htaccess file to convert all requests to lowercase as well, then the html should work. 

Thoughts?

Comment: The script will rename the files/folders to lower case no matter if all the letters are caps or all are lower case and one is CAPS

Comment: To be more precise, any combination of letters (lower case and/or upper case) will be converted in lower case

Comment: Right, but if the path in the HTML code is uppercase, that won't work unless I also use the .htaccess to rewrite the requests to all lowercase as well.

Comment: The script can be adapted/modified to convert to lowercase the paths inside the html files as well. I’m refering here only to the paths related to the name of the files/folders that are with caps... Everything else in the html files will remain the way they are

Answer (score 0):

You should write a test script to check all your HREF's (and navigation links) after adding the htaccess rules to rewrite all requests toLower. That would be enough to check how this proposed change could affect other areas of your website. The only thing I can think of if you're rewriting all requests, is what would happen to URLs of the sort `protocol://username:password@webserver.tld/login` type of requests, if you have any area of your website under Basic Auth premises.

Comment: We aren't using any authentication like that. It's an extremely simple host, there isn't even a site, just directories with HTML files in them. We send out links directly yo the HTML documents (this is just for showing samples to clients)

Comment: Well, I think you have everything you need to test this yourself then! Go for it!

Comment: You know it just dawned on my that I can't do that without also changing all the folder and file names to lowercase (which I can do with a script).  Sounds like I will have to do both.

Comment: If I recall correctly, apache rewrite engine accepts regular expression, so in theory you could only change whatever comes after the last `/`.

Comment: Yes, but I have to rename the path as well because they named and referenced the folders with incorrect case as well.

Comment: I'd try HBruin suggestion first. Then only if that module doesn't do the job, try Bogdan's script.